# How to refer back to equations

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I am using `\begin{equation} \end{equation}` to number my equations in my text. But I normally mention these equations in the further text. E.g., *In equation 3 ...*.

But if I change the former equation number I have to search in the text where I mentioned it.

Is there any way to link those numbers so when I change the equation number it automatically changes the furthers mentions about it in the text?

Comment: For this you must use `\label{eq.foo}` and then `\eqref{eq.foo}`.

Comment: Welcome! `\label{<identifier>}` and then `\ref{<identifier>}`. The first in the equation. The second where you want the cross-reference.

Comment: Sorry, but what is this eq.foo? @Sigur

Comment: @AndréGomes, it is any nickname for your equations. You can choose just to refer. Use different ones for different equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

`first` is an arbitrary identifier e.g. `emc2` or `a2o2h2` or whatever will have meaning for you. `first` is a bad example because the equation might not always be first. While this won't bother LaTeX, it will confuse me!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  abc\label{first}
\end{equation}
\ref{first}
\end{document}
```

[image: cross-reference]

If you load **amsmath**, then you can use `\eqref{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  abc\label{first}
\end{equation}
\eqref{first}
\end{document}
```

[image: eqref]

**cleveref** is a popular package for cross-referencing of all kinds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  abc\label{first}
\end{equation}
\cref{first}
\end{document}
```

[image: cleveref]

I prefer **fancyref**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  abc\label{eq:first}
\end{equation}
\fref{eq:first}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancyref]

In this case the `eq:` part of the identifier tells **fancyref** what kind of thing is referenced, whereas **cleveref** tries to figure this out from the context.